# Ionic Cordova Camera : Corrupted/Black Base64 image

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, ionic3

I'm trying to get the base64 of my image to be able to send it to an API but I have a corrumpu image or something like that because when I display it in chrome I have a black image. I can, however, display it in my app. I do not understand why also I have 2 log line with 2 different base64

```js
public takePicture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      imageData => {
        this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        this.form.base64_image = this.base64Image;
        console.log('BAse64 :');
        console.log(this.form.base64_image);
        this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
        this.photos.reverse();
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error : ' + err);
      }
    );
  }
```

I get that in log :

```
2019-04-06 20:05:40.939 19714-19714/com.test.app D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/8.js: Line 290 : data:image/jpeg;base64,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
2019-04-06 20:05:40.982 19714-19714/com.test.app I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(290)] "data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use file transfer for it. I was also facing the same problem so I used the file transfer using the API.

[Not able to convert the base64 to image path in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378852/not-able-to-convert-the-base64-to-image-path-in-ionic-4/)